# Half-closing TcpClient

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient

I'm having serious issue with half-closing a TcpClient. What I am trying to do is:

On the client:

1. Send a message
2. Shutdown the underlying socket for sending
3. Receive a response
4. Shutdown the underlying socket for reading (or, at this point, just close it)

On the server:

1. Receive a message
2. Shutdown the underlying socket for reading
3. Send a response
4. Shutdown the underlying socket for writing (or, at this point, just close it)

However, after the step 2 on either the client, or the server, I can't use the TcpClient's stream.
Here's a very simplified version of my code (without asynchronous calls, processing and cleaning up, and also using StreamReader and StreamWriter instead of an XmlSerializer):

```
        //initialize the connection between the server and the client
        var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 13546);
        listener.Start();
        var client = new TcpClient("127.0.0.1", 13546);
        var server = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
        listener.Stop();

        //CLIENT: send the message
        var cwriter = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());

        cwriter.Write("client's message");
        cwriter.Flush();

        client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);

        //SERVER: receive the message
        string msg;
        var sreader = new StreamReader(server.GetStream());

        msg = sreader.ReadToEnd();

        server.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Receive);

        //SERVER: send a response
        //Here the code fails on server.GetStream() - 
        //InvalidOperationException, apparently the whole connection is closed now

        var swriter = new StreamWriter(server.GetStream());

        swriter.Write(msg + " with server's response");
        swriter.Flush();

        server.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Send);

        //CLIENT: receive the message
        var creader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());

        var response = creader.ReadToEnd();

        client.Client.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Receive);
```

Is there any way to do this without using a raw socket? Is there something I'm getting wrong?

Comment: What does fail mean? The jump to raw sockets seems premature and arbitrary. Rather, fix the bug and you're good.

Comment: `StreamWriter` takes ownership of the stream passed to it. When it's garbage collected, the underlying stream is disposed as well. You would see this clearly if you disposed the `StreamWriter`, as you're supposed to (what with it being an `IDisposable`). You could use the constructor overload that leaves the stream open. Alternatively, don't bother with any of this -- if you need to access the underlying socket of a `TcpClient` you're usually doing it wrong. The socket doesn't really need to be shut down manually with proper abort logic.

Comment: @JeroenMostert good catch but the problem should not easily manifest itself. Does SR even have a finalizer? It should not. Also, shutting down can signal stream completion to the remote side. I guess shutting down receiving does not do much, yes.

Comment: @JeroenMostert In the actual code I'm using an XmlSerializer, which doesn't implement IDisposable, and the problem is still there. I used the StreamWriter and StreamReader to illustrate my issue easily, though maybe I should have just left the XmlSerializer.

Comment: @usr Added a comment about the exception in the code. As for shutting down receiving, it may be unnecessary, but I need to shut down sending to signal the other side that I'm done transmitting the data (the connection needs to be compatible with an implementation that assumes I do shut down sending after I'm done).

Comment: Did you read the exception? What is your interpretation of the message?

Comment: "This operation is not allowed on non-connected sockets." - which suggests that a Socket with sending shut down doesn't work with TcpClient - which is what led me to believe that I might have to use a raw socket instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `ReadToEnd` reads data up to the end of stream. By issuing `Client.Shutdown` you actually close the socket making it impossible to reuse it (at least in case of `TCPClient`). Here's the code of `GetStream()`

```
public NetworkStream GetStream() {
    if(Logging.On)Logging.Enter(Logging.Sockets, this, "GetStream", "");
    if (m_CleanedUp){
        throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);        
    }
    if (!Client.Connected) {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.net_notconnected));
    }
    if (m_DataStream==null) {
        m_DataStream = new NetworkStream(Client, true);
    }
    if(Logging.On)Logging.Exit(Logging.Sockets, this, "GetStream", m_DataStream);
    return m_DataStream;
}
```

As you can see, the error occures due to closed socket.

EDIT: It is ridiculously strange but I think I found the reason why it doesn't work properly. The reason is that `Shutdown` always sets flags for the entire socket as disconnected. Even though we are actually not closing it that way! If we preserve stream at the begining of the method we will not face this problem since the problem lies in `GetStream` method which checks socket's state. But we are probably exposed to some bugs when other code would check socket's state.

Comment: So it's not possible to do a half close with a TcpClient, then? That's a shame.

Comment: It is possible to half-close a connection. The open question is: Why is the socket fully closed if the code appears to half-close. Also, you can just call GetStream once at the beginning which leads to cleaner code anway. @Noctiphobia please do that and update the code.

Comment: @Noctiphobia ok I have rewritten the code and it seems like I can send data back and forth without any problems. Anyways, it would be safer to handle sockets explicitly if you want to reuse it for two way communication IMO

Comment: I say this is Defined Expected Behavior.  I always thought a TCP connections always implied two open streams, one in each direction.  Even if I do not send back a single byte and only Read/Consume/ACK incoming bytes the return connection must exist and be "up" from my codes point of view.  This is what I always thought at least.  That is why I was struck by the original question as being impossible by definition, even if you could use a garbage collection trick to pull it off.  Just my two bits.